# Pretty Date Intervals in Swift. NSCalendar components

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar

I'm trying to print a prettier version of a `timeIntervalSinceDate` e.g '10 days, 6 hours...'. But i'm failing to get NSCalendar components to work correctly.

**I get an "Extra argument 'toDate' in call" error with the following:**

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EE, dd MMM y hh:mm a zzz"

var dateString = "Wed, 08 Jun 2011 11:58 pm EDT"

var date: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!

var now = NSDate()

let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar()

let components = calendar.components(unitFlags: .CalendarUnitDay,
                                      fromDate: date,
                                        toDate: now,
                                       options: 0)

components.day
```

The 'toDate' feature is documented, so I'm not sure why I get the error?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two errors:

- The first parameter in a method does not have an external parameter name,
  so you must not specify `unitFlags:`.
- For "no options", specify `NSCalendarOptions(0)` or simply `nil`.

Together:

```
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitDay,
       fromDate: date, toDate: now, options: nil)
```

**Update for Swift 2:** NS_OPTIONS are now imported as conforming
to `OptionSetType`, and "no options" can be specified as the empty set:

```
let components = calendar.components(.Day,
    fromDate: date, toDate: now, options: [])
```

Comment: @lkemitchll: It should be `let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()`.

Comment: nice - I think the compiler error when using 0 instead of nil is a little misleading, but Swift is in it's infancy.

Comment: @Woodstock: NSCalendarOptions is not a number or enum. It is a struct which conforms to RawOptionSetType which in turn inherits from to NilLiteralConvertible ... that's why you can write `nil` here :)